# Can gomobile build app be published on appstore

Tags: ios, go, gomobile

`gomobile` build is a simple go mobile tool to build app,  it is easy to build ios / android app cross platform, but  can `gomobile` build an app (ios/android) to be published on the App Store or Google Play?

[Here](https://pt.slideshare.net/takuyaueda967/go-for-mobile-games) is a document to show how to publish go build app on Google Play.

However,  there is no document on how to publish an app on the App Store

how to do this,  is it possible ?

I tried on appstore,  it reports 
ERROR ITMS-90161: "Invalid Provisioning Profile. The provisioning profile included in the bundle com.company.app [Payload/App.app] is invalid

Answer (score 0):

First you need to create a runnable apk file using [gomobile](https://godoc.org/golang.org/x/mobile/cmd/gomobile) toolset.

Given that you have gomobile initialized and NDK installed

```
gomobile build -target=android -v -o=myApp.apk path/to/your/goProject
```

Or install directly into your phone (to test out first) with

```
gomobile install .....
```

If you use gomobile build, you may have to first sign your app using either jarsigner or [android studio](https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/app-signing.html)

Then follow instructions from [Google](https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/index.html) to finally publish into appstore

There is an [example Gomobile project](https://github.com/art4711/kk) on Github for more info

Comment: Thank you. But  I am asking for apple app store.

Comment: And do u know how to make the screen to be landscape, the default layout is portrait.